# the first index on response always shown every loading new data but didnt display on recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i implement a load more on recyclerview and call items 20 every scroll to the bottom. but the problem is my fist index is always available every time i scroll.
example on the log cat :

The first load :

```
2019-02-07 21:11:35.411 10665-10665/com.example.ilham.obatherbal D/herbal: Onresponse[{"albumId":1,"id":1,"title":"accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/92c952","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/92c952"},{"albumId":1,"id":2,"title":"reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/771796","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/771796"},{"albumId":1,"id":3,"title":"officia porro iure quia iusto qui ipsa ut modi","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/24f355","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/24f355"},{"albumId":1,"id":4,"title":"culpa odio esse rerum omnis laboriosam voluptate repudiandae","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/d32776","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/d32776"},{"albumId":1,"id":5,"title":"natus nisi omnis corporis facere molestiae rerum in","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/f66b97","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/f66b97"},{"albumId":1,"id":6,"title":"accusamus ea aliquid et amet sequi nemo","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/56a8c2","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/56a8c2"},{"albumId":1,"id":7,"title":"officia delectus consequatur vero aut veniam explicabo molestias","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/b0f7cc","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/b0f7cc"},{"albumId":1,"id":8,"title":"aut porro officiis laborum odit ea laudantium corporis","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/54176f","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/54176f"},{"albumId":1,"id":9,"title":"qui eius qui autem sed","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/51aa97","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/51aa97"},{"albumId":1,"id":10,"title":"beatae et provident et ut vel","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/810b14","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/810b14"},{"albumId":1,"id":11,"title":"nihil at amet non hic quia qui","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/1ee8a4","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/1ee8a4"},{"albumId":1,"id":12,"title":"mollitia soluta ut rerum eos aliquam consequatur perspiciatis maiores","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/66b7d2","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/66b7d2"},{"albumId":1,"id":13,"title":"repudiandae iusto deleniti rerum","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/197d29","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/197d29"},{"albumId":1,"id":14,"title":"est necessitatibus architecto ut laborum","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/61a65","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/61a65"},{"albumId":1,"id":15,"title":"harum dicta similique quis dolore earum ex qui","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/f9cee5","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/f9cee5"},{"albumId":1,"id":16,"title":"iusto sunt nobis quasi veritatis quas expedita voluptatum deserunt","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/fdf73e","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/fdf73e"},{"albumId":1,"id":17,"title":"natus doloribus necessitatibus ipsa","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/9c184f","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/9c184f"},{"albumId":1,"id":18,"title":"laboriosam odit nam necessitatibus et illum dolores reiciendis","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/1fe46f","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/1fe46f"},{"albumId":1,"id":19,"title":"perferendis nesciunt eveniet et optio a","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/56acb2","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/56acb2"},{"albumId":1,"id":20,"title":"assumenda voluptatem laboriosam enim consequatur veniam placeat reiciendis error","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/8985dc","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/8985dc"},{"albumId":1,"id":21,"title":"ad et natus qui","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/5e12c6","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/5e12c6"},{"albumId":1,"id":22,"title":"et ea illo et sit voluptas animi bland
2019-02-07 21:11:35.412 10665-10665/com.example.ilham.obatherbal D/herbal: jsonobject{"albumId":2,"id":63,"title":"facere animi autem quod dolor","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/4e557c","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/4e557c"}
2019-02-07 21:11:35.412 10665-10665/com.example.ilham.obatherbal D/herbal: jsonobject{"albumId":2,"id":64,"title":"doloremque culpa quia","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/cd5a92","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/cd5a92"}
```

The second load  :

```
2019-02-07 21:11:38.107 10665-10665/com.example.ilham.obatherbal D/herbal: Onresponse[{"albumId":1,"id":1,"title":"accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/92c952","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/92c952"},{"albumId":1,"id":2,"title":"reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/771796","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/771796"},{"albumId":1,"id":3,"title":"officia porro iure quia iusto qui ipsa ut modi","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/24f355","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/24f355"},{"albumId":1,"id":4,"title":"culpa odio esse rerum omnis laboriosam voluptate repudiandae","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/d32776","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/d32776"},{"albumId":1,"id":5,"title":"natus nisi omnis corporis facere molestiae rerum in","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/f66b97","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/f66b97"},{"albumId":1,"id":6,"title":"accusamus ea aliquid et amet sequi nemo","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/56a8c2","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/56a8c2"},{"albumId":1,"id":7,"title":"officia delectus consequatur vero aut veniam explicabo molestias","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/b0f7cc","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/b0f7cc"},{"albumId":1,"id":8,"title":"aut porro officiis laborum odit ea laudantium corporis","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/54176f","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/54176f"},{"albumId":1,"id":9,"title":"qui eius qui autem sed","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/51aa97","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/51aa97"},{"albumId":1,"id":10,"title":"beatae et provident et ut vel","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/810b14","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/810b14"},{"albumId":1,"id":11,"title":"nihil at amet non hic quia qui","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/1ee8a4","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/1ee8a4"},{"albumId":1,"id":12,"title":"mollitia soluta ut rerum eos aliquam consequatur perspiciatis maiores","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/66b7d2","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/66b7d2"},{"albumId":1,"id":13,"title":"repudiandae iusto deleniti rerum","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/197d29","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/197d29"},{"albumId":1,"id":14,"title":"est necessitatibus architecto ut laborum","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/61a65","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/61a65"},{"albumId":1,"id":15,"title":"harum dicta similique quis dolore earum ex qui","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/f9cee5","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/f9cee5"},{"albumId":1,"id":16,"title":"iusto sunt nobis quasi veritatis quas expedita voluptatum deserunt","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/fdf73e","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/fdf73e"},{"albumId":1,"id":17,"title":"natus doloribus necessitatibus ipsa","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/9c184f","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/9c184f"},{"albumId":1,"id":18,"title":"laboriosam odit nam necessitatibus et illum dolores reiciendis","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/1fe46f","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/1fe46f"},{"albumId":1,"id":19,"title":"perferendis nesciunt eveniet et optio a","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/56acb2","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/56acb2"},{"albumId":1,"id":20,"title":"assumenda voluptatem laboriosam enim consequatur veniam placeat reiciendis error","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/8985dc","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/8985dc"},{"albumId":1,"id":21,"title":"ad et natus qui","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/5e12c6","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/5e12c6"},{"albumId":1,"id":22,"title":"et ea illo et sit voluptas animi bland
2019-02-07 21:11:38.108 10665-10665/com.example.ilham.obatherbal D/herbal: jsonobject{"albumId":2,"id":84,"title":"aliquam dolorem ut modi ratione et assumenda impedit","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/b5205d","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/b5205d"}
2019-02-07 21:11:38.108 10665-10665/com.example.ilham.obatherbal D/herbal: jsonobject{"albumId":2,"id":85,"title":"ullam delectus architecto sint error","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/eb7e7f","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/eb7e7f"}
2019-02-07 21:11:38.108 10665-10665/com.example.ilham.obatherbal D/herbal: jsonobject{"albumId":2,"id":86,"title":"qui vel ut odio consequuntur","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/fd5751","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/fd5751"}
2019-02-07 21:11:38.108 10665-10665/com.example.ilham.obatherbal D/herbal: jsonobject{"albumId":2,"id":87,"title":"eos nihil sunt accusantium omnis","url":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/600\/224566","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/via.placeholder.com\/150\/224566"}
```

on the example above, there is always got response the first index (in this example on key id:1} but there is no that data on the recyclerview. it start from the second data. Sometimes my progress bar also didnt hide when the data was loaded.

this is my adapter code :

```
   public class herbalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{
    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;
    private Context mCtx;
    List<herbalModel> herbalModelList;

    public herbalAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView,Context mCtx, List<herbalModel> herbalModelList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.herbalModelList = herbalModelList;
        if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView
                    .getLayoutManager();


            recyclerView
                    .addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                               int dx, int dy) {
                            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                            totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                            lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager
                                    .findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                            if (!loading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                                // End has been reached
                                // Do something
                                if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                                    onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                                }
                                loading = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return herbalModelList.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                      int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
            CardView v = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.cardview_herbal, parent,false);
//        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_herbal,null);
           vh = new herbalViewHolder(v);
        } else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.progressbar_item, parent, false);

            vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof herbalViewHolder) {

            herbalModel detailherbal= (herbalModel) herbalModelList.get(position);

            ((herbalViewHolder) holder).namaHerbal.setText(detailherbal.getNama());
            ((herbalViewHolder) holder).khasiatHerbal.setText(detailherbal.getKhasiat());
            Glide.with(mCtx)
                .load(detailherbal.getThumbnail())
                .into(((herbalViewHolder) holder).thumbnail);
            final String idHerbal =detailherbal.getId();
            ((herbalViewHolder) holder).itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(mCtx, detailHerbal.class);
                i.putExtra("idHerbal", idHerbal);
                mCtx.startActivity(i);

            }
        });



        } else {
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
    }

    public void setLoaded() {
        loading = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return herbalModelList.size();
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
    }

    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ProgressBar progressBar;

        public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        }
    }

    public static class herbalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView namaHerbal,khasiatHerbal;
        ImageView thumbnail;
        public herbalViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            namaHerbal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nama_herbal);
            khasiatHerbal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.khasiat_herbal);
            thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gambar_herbal);
        }
    }

    public void filterlist (ArrayList<herbalModel> filteredList)
    {
        herbalModelList =filteredList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

this is my code on activity :

```
    public class herbal extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    herbalAdapter mAdapter;
    List <herbalModel> herbalModels;
    EditText search;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private Handler handler;

    private static final String TAG = "herbal";

    public herbal() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_herbal, container, false);
        herbalModels = new ArrayList<>();

        RequestQueue queue = MySingleton.getInstance(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
        get20Data();

        sortData(rootView);
        StartRecyclerView(rootView);
        return rootView ;

    }




    private void StartRecyclerView(View rootView) {
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_herbal);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        // use a linear layout manager
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // create an Object for Adapter
        mAdapter = new herbalAdapter(mRecyclerView,getActivity(),herbalModels);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                //add null , so the adapter will check view_type and show progress bar at bottom
                herbalModels.add(null);
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(herbalModels.size() - 1);
                handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //   remove progress item
                        herbalModels.remove(herbalModels.size() - 1);
                        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(herbalModels.size());
                        //add items one by one
                        int start = herbalModels.size();
                        int end = start + 20;
                        loadMore(start,end);

                       }
                },2000);

            }
        });




    }

    private void loadMore(final int start, final int end) {
        String url ="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                        Log.d(TAG,"Onresponse"+jsonArray.toString());
                        for(int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.d(TAG,"jsonobject"+jsonObject);
                                herbalModels.add(
                                        new herbalModel(
                                                jsonObject.getString("title"),
                                                "Khasiat",
                                                jsonObject.getString("albumId"),
                                                jsonObject.getString("id"),
                                                jsonObject.getString("thumbnailUrl")
                                        )
                                );
                                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(herbalModels.size());
                            }
                            catch(JSONException e) {

                            }
                        }
                        mAdapter.setLoaded();

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Log.d(TAG,"Onerror"+volleyError.toString());
                    }
                });
        MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(request);

    }
private void get20Data() {

        String url ="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                        Log.d(TAG,"Onresponse"+jsonArray.toString());
                        for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.d(TAG,"jsonobject"+jsonObject);
                                herbalModels.add(
                                        new herbalModel(
                                                jsonObject.getString("title"),
                                                "Khasiat",
                                                jsonObject.getString("albumId"),
                                                jsonObject.getString("id"),
                                                jsonObject.getString("thumbnailUrl")
                                        )
                                );

                            }
                            catch(JSONException e) {

                            }
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Log.d(TAG,"Onerror"+volleyError.toString());
                    }
                });
        MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
```

this is the progress bar when it doesnt hide after success got response from server
[progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQPYb.png)